Can an entity predict itself?
I am not into philosophy, but this question came into my mind 2 days ago. It seemed like a philosophical question.
Consider any kind of entity, conscious or unconscious. ( The definitions are vague, but i don't know any other way to describe the problem. )
Suppose this entity, can speak in English language. And can somehow always predict what any entity speaking English will say at a given instant or interval of time. From "given" i mean as an input from other entities, most probably humans...
(edit) ----=----
Now if the entity plays any trick like uttering same word/s in regular intervals at least humans would be able to recognize it. Say by asking to predict after 3 hours, and then again after 3 hours.... At least a pattern would be recognized.
The entity sure can't be a computer, else it would obviously be trivial since no computer can always predict what humans will utter at any time, at least not provably so.  ----=----
Can it possibly predict what it itself is going to utter at any given instant of time or interval. ?
Now, I myself couldn't come to any conclusion, but my approach was this - that in such a situation the entity must be developing some sense of choice , while predicting its words to be uttered in the given time. Like, what if the phenomenon of being asked such a question alters what it was going to utter... ( You see why this is so confusing for me )...

Trivially yes; all it has to do is say "radish" at regular intervals of thirty minutes, and then it would be perfectly capable of predicting that it is going to say "radish."

@causative i would consider that as cheating..... nothing trivial about that...

Cheating according to what rules?

@causative is the question that vague to understand ? i thought i made it reasonably clear. ok so i am making an edit, you may see the edit to get a better understanding

So your additional rule is that humans shouldn't be able to tell the entity apart from a normal human acting normally? In that case, the entity can be a computer running a simulation of a human brain. It can use the simulation to utter words that seem normal for a human. It can also "fast-forward" the simulation to predict what words it would say later.

You say "suppose can somehow always predict any entity", and this answers your question. "Always" means always and "any" means any, it can predict itself in particular, no "phenomenon being asked" can alter what it predicted. And if it is not "always" and "any" then the question is meaningless. You do not say how it predicts, so you do not provide any relevant information to answer it.

How can a simple question be so much easily misintrepreted ? Its almost as if its been done on purpose to hide some sort of insecurity ... ..  In any case,the question is still open, and I know people who actually have something substantial to say here either haven't read this question... or need more details but for some reason are hesitant to ask for it....

From your comment:

How can a simple question be so much easily misintrepreted[sic]?

The simplicity of asking a question does not always correlate to the simplicity of answering it or even interpreting it.  This question bears some similarity to other self-referential questions like "Can God create a rock so heavy that even he cannot lift it?" in that it's easy to write but the details that follow in answering are murky.
I will not be able to provide one answer, but I can point to some of the interesting corner cases in the language.

Suppose this entity, can speak in english language. And can somehow always predict what any entity speaking english will say at a given instant or interval of time.

What do you mean by "speak?"  Even the little words can be tricky.  If speaking implies understanding, then that implies this entity must be sentient.  If speaking merely implies the utterance of sounds corresponding to a grammar, then the entity may be an algorithm.  This distinction is important, and is well captured in the classic argument of the Chineese Room.
If it is an algorithm, we go down one path.  In this path, there's a self-similarity built into the algorithm.  As mentioned in comments, one approach is to simply develop a tic and repeat the same thing every time.  You called this "cheating," which suggests to me you're looking for something more robust.  Douglas Hofstadter explored what he called "strange loops" which appear to exhibit much of the behaviors you are interested in.  He quite literally wrote multiple books about the topic, so doing it justice will take more than a stack exchange answer.
If it is sentient, we go down another path.  A key question will come up which is whether the entity has free-will.  Sentience and free will are not the same, but are definitely entwined.  It's hard to consider one without the other -- and neither topic is a simple one.
Regardless of the sentience of the entity, your free-will is at stake as well.  If an oracle (and, if we are honest with ourselves, an oracle is what you describe) can definitively say you will say X at time Y, will you have any capability to say anything else?  Do you have the freewill to refuse?  In theory the answer becomes no.
What about adversarial actors?  What if the oracle says that you will say "yes" at a given time, and an adversary then puts you into a position to turn that into a poor response ("I ask the defendant, did you murder these people?")  If they can do this, that suggests that the presence of this entity raises questions about your own free will.  On the other hand, if this can't happen, that suggests the entity can not only predict what is said, but the context it is said (such that you would be willing to say such things of your own free will).
This is starting to go down the road of simulation theory, asking whether the entirety of our subjective existence can be simulated.
Not bad for a simple question.
An interesting corner case I remember from physics deals with time travel, wormholes and causality.  A paper studied a case of a billiard ball being thrown through a wormhole to travel back in time.  They studied patterns where the path the billiard ball took (now in the past) intersected with its existing path, knocking it off course so it never went into the wormhole.  They wanted to study the paradox involved.  What they found was that for any self-conflicting scenario with one wormhole and one billiard ball, there was always a solution where the ball came out of the past wormhole at a slightly different angle, such that it glanced off the original ball, deflecting it exactly onto the right path to take that different trajectory in the first place.  They posited (but never proved) that this would be true for any number of balls or other objects.
Mind you that's physics and time travel, and this is philosophy and prediction.  But there were enough interesting parallels that it might jog some new ideas for you.

You say that the predictor should predict what the speaker (here, itself) will say at a given instant or interval of time. From "given" you mean as an input from other entities, most probably humans.  With this in mind, let the human ask:
"Immediately following this question, are you going to give me a negative answer?"
A noncommittal or non-propositional answer fails to answer the question.  An answer that does answer the question refutes itself.
If I misunderstood the intent of your question, please clarify.
--Edit--
Taking causative's point, and using your point that "being asked such a question [possibly] alters what it was going to utter", here's my second try.
Alice asks the predictor at 10pm to predict everything it will say in the next hour.  It answers, finishing at 10:01.  It is night, the sky is clear, and participants are outside.  The flash of a supernova appears at 10:02, and Bob asks the predictor "what is that bright new object in the sky?"  Since the light from the supernova was outside the past light-cone of the predictor at 10:01pm, it has no basis for knowledge of Bob's impending observation and question.  So either it fails to respond to Bob's question (which seems to be against your rules), or it fails to predict that response.

OP didn't say the entity is obligated to answer verbal questions truthfully. The entity could be making accurate predictions that it does not speak of verbally.

Re-reading the OP, you seem correct that the predictor is not obliged to answer truthfully.  The OP does mention that it can speak English, however, which suggests that it is meant to answer verbally.

There are two kind of facts to be predicted, physical (empirical) and metaphysical (rational, ideal):
Metaphysical: metaphysical facts, that is, what is rational, what exists in our minds, what is independent of sense experience; that can be predicted with accuracy. For example, the probability of 1+1 being 2 is 100% and for it being 2.1 is 0%. We can trust logic to the point that metaphysically, we almost don't need probabilities. Metaphysical facts are ruled by logic. If you imagine a typical free fall scenario, the probability of the body to fall down is 100% forever.
Physical: physical facts, that is, what happens outside of our minds, what we perceive with the senses, what can be measured, etc.; those facts can never be predictable to 100% or 0% probability. There's always some probability, not 0%, for a bunch of monkeys writing randomly in typing machines, for infinite time, to produce the complete works of William Shakespeare. There are literally infinite elements that impact physical reality; any prediction can always take a limited number of such infinite possible circumstances into account.
So, independently of your physical entity being cosmic or marine, solid or liquid, independently of its quality, size, trustability, sincerity, quantity of transistors, color, brand, etc., independently of any attributes, just if it is physical: there are no 0% or 100% probable predictions in the physical realm.
